# How to fix Number.isInteger() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, integer

When I press a button then it retrieve a value from textarea 
HTML code

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="17" id="list_card" placeholder="Insert Card Numbers"></textarea>
<input  name="infoDominio" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" value="Add Card" onclick="add_card()">
```

Javascript code

```
var res = myVar[0];
var ress = 4567891;
var val1 = Number.isInteger(res);
var val2 = Number.isInteger(ress);
document.write(myVar[0]+" "+val1+" "+val2+" "+res);
```

Where `myVar[0] = 4567891; myVar[0]` value comes from textarea. But I can't get proper output. I think val1 should be true. Output looks Like this. Would you suggest me how can I get val1=true.

```
4567891 false true 4567891
```

Comment: `var res = parseInt(myVar[0]);`

Comment: One is a `String` composed of digits, the other is a `Number`.

Comment: If input is set  756e775 then output  '756e775 true true 756'  It's not correct

Comment: check the answer using regex

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` will produce a `string` and not an `integer`.

You need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt) it as `integer`:

```
var res = parseInt(myVar[0]);
```

---

*As a side note:* the user may type a non-integer value in your textarea. Maybe are you looking for `input type="number"/>`?

Comment: if we set parseInt then we enter float value so output is true in isInteger so Number(var) is useful

Answer (score 1):

I think this way useful for you

```js
function add_card(){
myVar =  document.getElementById("list_card").value;
var res = Number(myVar);
var ress = 4567891;
var val1 = Number.isInteger(res);
var val2 = Number.isInteger(ress);
document.write(myVar+" "+val1+" "+val2+" "+res);
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="17" id="list_card" placeholder="Insert Card Numbers"></textarea>
<input  name="infoDominio" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" value="Add Card" onclick="add_card()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change val1 assignment to this

```
var val1 = Number.isInteger(parseInt(res));
```

Comment: if we set parseInt then we enter float value so output is true in isInteger so Number(var) is useful

Comment: @ImBS He says text area will be populated by card numbers which are not of float type.

Comment: oh sorry for that but it is appx bug so i might be consider in it and place comment and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression

- /^ -> start of string
- \d+ -> one or more occurrence of digit (\d)
- $/ -> end of string

```js
function add_card(){
var res = document.getElementById('list_card').value;
var ress = 4567891;
var val1 = /^\d+$/.test(res);
var val2 = /^\d+$/.test(ress);
document.write(res+" "+val1+" "+val2+" "+ress);
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="17" id="list_card" placeholder="Insert Card Numbers"></textarea>
<input  name="infoDominio" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" value="Add Card" onclick="add_card()">
```